# Incomplete list returned from python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, scroll

I would like to return all the liked tracks from a Soundcloud profile and I have to scroll down to the bottom of the page for it to dynamically load all li elements from the ul. The number of list items is 2,589.

My Problem is that it only gets 1978 tracks from the list whereby the first and last track are both in it. That means that there are songs missing in  between.

Could it be that the number of items is too large?

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from time import sleep

SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 1


def browse_liked_tracks() -> list:
    options = Options()
    options.headless = True
    firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    firefox_profile.set_preference('permissions.default.image', 2)
     firefox_profile.set_preference('dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.libflashplayer.so', False)
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, firefox_profile=firefox_profile)
    driver.get('https://soundcloud.com/officialdekon/likes')
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    while True:
        last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

        # Scroll down to bottom
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

        # Wait to load page
        sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

        # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        if new_height == last_height:

            # try again (can be removed)
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

            # Wait to load page
            sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

            # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
            new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

            # check if the page height has remained the same
            if new_height == last_height:
                # if so, you are done
                break
            # if not, move on to the next loop

    tracks = [t.get_attribute('aria-label').split('Track:')[1] for t in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="sound streamContext"]')]

    driver.quit()

    return tracks


def file_writer(tracks: list):
    with open('dekon_liked_tracks.txt', 'w') as f:
        for track in tracks:
            f.write('{}\n'.format(track))


def main():
    file_writer(browse_liked_tracks())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Try to put a sleep before break. If you save the HTML into a file before get elements in "track" variable you see all elements?

Comment: @Wonka There seem to be 1069 items in the stored html file

Comment: @Wonka The sleep before the break unfortunately didn't help either.

Comment: Then try this, just before track = [get...] save html ( with open("00.html", "w+") as f:     f.write(driver.page_source.encode("utf-8"))  )  . Print (len(tracks) ) after get tracks. Open html saved, go to console dev tools, write < $x("//div[@class='sound streamContext']") > (without < > ) and check num count

Comment: Unfortunately I can't inspect the saved html in the browser as it tells me that it can't find the page. Before I used string matching on the html file to find the num count of the divs